# x86_64 does not show up on M1 Pro

Tags: apple-m1, apple-silicon

I have an Apple M1 Pro and I am using Rosetta in the terminal. I have Rosetta checked when using the terminal, but I don't know if Rosetta is being applied.
I am not sure if Rosetta is applied or not.
Specifically, when Resetta is checked, I get the following results.

```
arch
arm64

uname -m
arm64
```

On the other hand, when Resetta is not checked, the result is as follows.

```
arch
i386

uname -m
arm64
```

I thought that `uname -m` was expected to show `x86_64`, but it only shows arm64, is there something wrong with the setting?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211861 ?

Comment: Thanks. It seems that MacBook succeeded to install Rosetta. But terminal checked using Rosetta showed not x86_64 also arm64.

Comment: Installing software will never change the output for `uname -m` or `arch`. (unless the software installs other versions of `uname` or `arch`.... )

Answer (score -4):

Solved. The setting of `.zshrc` is invalid.

Comment: It's not entirely clear how your answer relates to your question.

Comment: Or it is entirely unclear how your answer relates to the question...    Which setting, in your `.zshrc` is invalid? and why ?

Comment: Yes, actually I don't understand why `.zshrc` relates to my question. I have deleted the wrong setting, so I can't show it. I remember that the setting is related to make a path of `coreutils`.